# I can not recover the id in my server Express Js to delete in my BD

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, express

I would like to remove a line from my bd recovering the id. However nothing is removed.I sent the id in http. 
I have no error code, but I have the impression that the server side it does not retrieve the id that I send him.

My code in my Service Angular :

```
function removeTask(id){
    var promise = $http({
        method: "DELETE",
        url: GENERAL_CONFIG.API_ENDPOINT + "todos",
        data: id
    }).then(function success(response) {
        return response.data;
        console.log(promise)

    }, function error(response) {
        //$rootScope.token = "";
        //$location.path("/home");
    });
    console.log(id);
    return promise;
}
```

My code in my server Express JS :

```
Index.js : 

router.delete('/', function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    var updatePromise = service.removeTodoList(req.body);
    updatePromise.catch(function(){
        res.sendStatus(500);
    });   
    updatePromise.then(function(rows){
        res.sendStatus(200);
    });
});

Service.js : 


todoService.removeTodoList = function removeTodoList (id){
    var taskValues = id ;
    console.log(id);
    return dbHandler.query('DELETE FROM todolist WHERE id=?;',[taskValues]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your endpoint url is `url: GENERAL_CONFIG.API_ENDPOINT + "todos",`
whereas in index.js you are using `router.delete('/', function(req,res){`
it should be `router.delete('/todos', function(req,res){`

Comment: If I add :

router.delete('/todos', function(req,res){
  var updatePromise = service.removeTodoList(req.body);
   updatePromise.catch(function(){
    res.sendStatus(500);
  });    updatePromise.then(function(rows){
    res.sendStatus(200);
  });
});

I am an error 404 !

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$http({
    method: "DELETE",
    url: GENERAL_CONFIG.API_ENDPOINT + 'todos/' + id
})
```

And

```
router.delete('/:id', function(req,res){
    console.log(req.params.id);
    var updatePromise = service.removeTodoList(req.params.id);
    updatePromise.catch(function(){
        res.sendStatus(500);
    });   
    updatePromise.then(function(rows){
        res.sendStatus(204);
    });
});
```